# Spring Dependency for Wicket 1.5.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependencies, wicket

I am developing an application with Wicket-Hibernate-Spring, where I am using Wicket 1.5.5.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>googlecode</id>
        <url>http://jqwicket.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.jqwicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>jqwicket</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now what will be the dependency for Spring and Hibernate? I want to use latest version of every component(not beta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a repository search engine, such as the official one : http://search.maven.org/

By searching "[hibernate-core](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-core%7C4.1.2%7Cjar)", you'll find the 4.1.2 version :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

For the Spring/Hibernate integration, search for "[spring-orm](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-orm%7C3.1.1.RELEASE%7Cjar)" :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me if I use hibernate-core 4.1.2 then what will be the hsqldb's version? Can I set <groupId>hsqldb</groupId><artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId><version>1.8.0.10</version> with this hibernate-core?

Comment: HSQLDB is not linked to Hibernate, so use whatever version you want.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use spring beans in wicket pages you can add the wicket-spring integration dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

The jar `wicket-spring-annot` was merged into `wicket-spring` 1.4, so it isn't necessary.

More info [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring.html)

Answer (score 1):

Get Wicket and Spring dependencies, to integrate both, you need “wicket-spring.jar“.

```
<project ..>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Wicket framework-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Integrate Wicket with Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j-log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```